# Refraction of a Ray of Light

Tags: optics, visible-light, refraction, faster-than-light

Why can no medium have a refractive index less than 1? Explain with Snell's Laws of Refraction of Light.

Comment: [The refractive index can be less than one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/436329/)

Comment: ... and materials in the EUV (wavelength < ~ 10 nm) have n < 1