# Is it possible to have a medium rarer than vacuum?

Tags: optics, refraction, faster-than-light

I was wondering whether it is possible to have a medium rarer than vacuum. If that is possible then we can increase the speed of light beyond $c$. Might sound like a weird question.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/436329/2451 and links therein.

Comment: only if it is well-done. then you will have a rare medium that is well-done.